# Tensorflow Object detection is not accurate , even though loss is low

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, object-detection, pre-trained-model

I'm using " faster_rcnn_inception_v2_pets " as a pretrained model , 
I labeled my images with labelImg .
The wierd thing is , even when I'm entering an image from train , my model can't identify objects in it correctly and bounding boxes are tremendously incorrect .[As shown in this image my step and loss ratios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuCNc.png)

This is my config file for R-CNN

```html
# Faster R-CNN with Inception v2, configured for Oxford-IIIT Pets Dataset.
# Users should configure the fine_tune_checkpoint field in the train config as
# well as the label_map_path and input_path fields in the train_input_reader and
# eval_input_reader. Search for "PATH_TO_BE_CONFIGURED" to find the fields that
# should be configured.

model {
  faster_rcnn {
    num_classes: 2
    image_resizer {
      keep_aspect_ratio_resizer {
        min_dimension: 600
        max_dimension: 1024
      }
    }
    feature_extractor {
      type: 'faster_rcnn_inception_v2'
      first_stage_features_stride: 16
    }
    first_stage_anchor_generator {
      grid_anchor_generator {
        scales: [0.25, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        aspect_ratios: [0.5, 1.0, 2.0]
        height_stride: 16
        width_stride: 16
      }
    }
    first_stage_box_predictor_conv_hyperparams {
      op: CONV
      regularizer {
        l2_regularizer {
          weight: 0.0
        }
      }
      initializer {
        truncated_normal_initializer {
          stddev: 0.01
        }
      }
    }
    first_stage_nms_score_threshold: 0.0
    first_stage_nms_iou_threshold: 0.7
    first_stage_max_proposals: 300
    first_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    first_stage_objectness_loss_weight: 1.0
    initial_crop_size: 14
    maxpool_kernel_size: 2
    maxpool_stride: 2
    second_stage_box_predictor {
      mask_rcnn_box_predictor {
        use_dropout: false
        dropout_keep_probability: 1.0
        fc_hyperparams {
          op: FC
          regularizer {
            l2_regularizer {
              weight: 0.0
            }
          }
          initializer {
            variance_scaling_initializer {
              factor: 1.0
              uniform: true
              mode: FAN_AVG
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
    second_stage_post_processing {
      batch_non_max_suppression {
        score_threshold: 0.0
        iou_threshold: 0.6
        max_detections_per_class: 100
        max_total_detections: 300
      }
      score_converter: SOFTMAX
    }
    second_stage_localization_loss_weight: 2.0
    second_stage_classification_loss_weight: 1.0
  }
}

train_config: {
  batch_size: 1
  optimizer {
    momentum_optimizer: {
      learning_rate: {
        manual_step_learning_rate {
          initial_learning_rate: 0.0010
          schedule {
            step: 5000
            learning_rate: .00008
          }
          schedule {
            step: 9000
            learning_rate: .000008
          }
        }
      }
      momentum_optimizer_value: 0.9
    }
    use_moving_average: false
  }
  gradient_clipping_by_norm: 10.0
  fine_tune_checkpoint: "/home/technique/Bureau/TF2.0/models/research/object_detection/faster_rcnn_inception_v2_coco_2018_01_28/model.ckpt"
  from_detection_checkpoint: true
  load_all_detection_checkpoint_vars: true
  # Note: The below line limits the training process to 200K steps, which we
  # empirically found to be sufficient enough to train the pets dataset. This
  # effectively bypasses the learning rate schedule (the learning rate will
  # never decay). Remove the below line to train indefinitely.
  num_steps: 10000
  data_augmentation_options {
    random_horizontal_flip {
    }
  }
}


train_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/technique/Bureau/TF2.0/models/research/object_detection/train.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/technique/Bureau/TF2.0/models/research/object_detection/training/objectdetection.pbtxt"
}

eval_config: {
  metrics_set: "coco_detection_metrics"
  num_examples: 1101
}

eval_input_reader: {
  tf_record_input_reader {
    input_path: "/home/technique/Bureau/TF2.0/models/research/object_detection/test.record"
  }
  label_map_path: "/home/technique/Bureau/TF2.0/models/research/object_detection/training/objectdetection.pbtxt"
  shuffle: false
  num_readers: 1
}
```

---

Actually I've used data augmentation techniques , split my data more efficiently ,so that my model can learn all possibilities , And I've let my model learn for 200 000 steps.
In that time detection complete.

Comment: In my case this issue was due to 1:-pb file getting corrupted while downloading from colab, 2:-Not using the latest ckpt for exporting pb.

Comment: @sreagm actually I insisted on picking latest ckpt do you have other ideas ?

Comment: A loss of 0.1 is *way* too high, and 301 steps are *way* to low for object detection, specially with a batch size of 1 and a large number of parameters. You need to train a lot more.